# C# dobrando valor sozinho

Tags: c#, .net

Estou apendendo C#, mas o código abaixo dobra o valor e encerra inesperadamente. Alguém pode dar uma olhada?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float a, b = 0;
            float resul = 0;
            string dado;


            Console.WriteLine("digite o primeiro valor");
            dado = Console.ReadLine();
            a = float.Parse(dado);
            Console.WriteLine("Digite o segundo valor");
            b = float.Parse(dado);
            resul = a + b;

            if (resul > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(resul);

            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("O valor" + resul,"é muito abaixo do esperado");

            }

            Console.WriteLine("encerre esse programa digitando qualquer tecla");
                Console.ReadLine();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Faltou um `Console.ReadLine();` para ler o segundo valor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como foi mencionado no comentário, faltou adicionar a seguinte linha antes de atribuir o valor à variável `b`

```
dado = Console.ReadLine();
b = float.Parse(dado);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

No codigo

```
Console.WriteLine("Digite o segundo valor");
            b = float.Parse(dado);
```

Você esta fazendo um parse do dado sem ler o dado do console.
então quando vocês faz `A + B`, o B está como o mesmo valor de A, por isso esta dobrando o A no resultado.

Já o fechamento inesperado se dá pelo codigo

```
 else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("O valor" + resul,"é muito abaixo do esperado");

            }
```

Neste trecho faltou o + para concatenar a variavel result com o texto.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro de tudo, as variáveis devem ser inicializadas. Porém, o código pode ser mais simplificado, tanto para melhor entendimento, quanto na leitura do código em si. Observe abaixo o código com a alteração e compare com o seu.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConsoleApp5
 {
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        decimal a = 0; 
        decimal b = 0;
        decimal resul = 0;  

        Console.WriteLine("digite o primeiro valor");
        a = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Digite o segundo valor");
        b = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        resul = a + b;

        if (resul > 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resul);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O valor " + resul + " é muito abaixo do esperado");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("encerre esse programa digitando qualquer tecla...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
   }
 }
```

Agora sim, vai funcionar perfeitamente.